# Isoperimetric inequality for non-spherical multivariate Gaussian

Tags: probability-theory, differential-geometry, reference-request, upper-lower-bounds, concentration-of-measure

**Disclaimer:** Sorry in advance, if the question is not very reasonable.  Recently (like a few days ago...), I've started studying isoperimetric inequalities, and my thoughts on the subject are rather cloudy with lots of black holes.

## Setup

So, the classical Gaussian Isoperimetric inequality states that

> **[GIPI]** if $d\gamma_d(x):= (2\pi)^{-d/2}\exp(-\|x\|_2^2/2)dx$ is the Gaussian measure on $\mathbb R^d$ and $B$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R^d$, then
>   $$
> \gamma_d(B_\epsilon) \ge \Phi(\Phi^{-1}(\gamma_d(B)) + \epsilon),\;\forall \epsilon > 0
> $$

where:

- $B_\epsilon := \{x \in \mathbb R^d | \|x-A\|_2^2 \le \epsilon\}$ is $\epsilon$-neighborhood/blowup of $B$
- the function $\Phi(z): = \int_{-\infty}^zd\gamma_1(z)$ defines the CDF of the 1D standard Gaussian and $\Phi^{-1}$ is its inverse.

A corollary to this inequality (see Otto et Villani 2000, for example) says that

> **[GIPI Corollary]** if $\epsilon \ge \sqrt{2\log(1/\gamma_d(B))}$, then
>   $$
> \gamma_d(B_\epsilon) \ge 1 - \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\epsilon-\sqrt{2\log(1/\gamma_d(B))})^2).
> $$

I'm interested in "simple" generalizations of **[GIPI]** and **[GIPI Corollary]**.

## Question 1

I know there are works (e.g Otto et Villani 2000, Bobkov 1999, etc.) which generalize this to more general log-concave distributions $d\mu = e^{-V}dx$ (coupled with even more general curved manifolds with lower bounded Ricci curvature), but it's hard to get one's hand on precise formulae (e.g involving the modulus of strong-convexity of the potential $V$, etc.). As a concrete example, suppose $V$ is twice continuously differentiable with $\operatorname{Hess}(V) \succeq C \operatorname{I}_d$,
what analogues of **[GIPI]** and **[GIPI Corollary]** do we get ?

## Question 2

In particular, what analogues of **[GIPI]** and **[GIPI Corollary]** do we get when we instead consider an non-spherical Gaussian distribution $d\gamma_{\mu,\Sigma} := (2\pi\operatorname{det}(\Sigma))^{-d/2}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^T\Sigma^{-1}x)$, with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ (positive definite) ?

## Observation

It turns out that explicit answers to both questions can be derived from [Corollary 3.2 Bobkov et al.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.397.5431&rep=rep1&type=pdf)  For example, we have a multi-variate Gaussian version of **[GIPI Corollary]** by simply replacing the 2 appearing in the square-root and the fraction (i.e $\frac{1}{2}$) with $2$ $\times$ the smallest eigenvalue of covariance matrix $\Sigma$. I can writeup a self-contained answer, but I don't know if this is a good idea since I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: It turns out that explicit answers to both questions can be derived from Corollary 3.2 Bobkov et al. http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.397.5431&rep=rep1&type=pdf.  For example, we have a multi-variate Gaussian version of **[GIPI Corollary]** by simply replacing the 2 appearing in the square-root and the fraction (i.e $\frac{1}{2}$) with $2$ $\times$ the smallest eigenvalue of covariance matrix $\Sigma$. I can writeup a self-contained answer, but I don't know if this is a good idea since I asked the question in the first place.

Comment: If you now have an answer, you are even encouraged to answer your own question! (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer))

Comment: @RhysSteele Ok, I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the works of [Bobkov et al. (1999)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.397.5431&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [Otto et Villani (2000)](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/014.OV-Talagrand.pdf), and even more recently [Otto et Reznikoff (2006)](https://www.mis.mpg.de/fileadmin/otto/OR_LSI_preprint.pdf), contain elements of solution to the questions I asked. I'll provide a quasi self-contained answer, hoping it will be helpful to a general public (like myself) without kungfu-panda-level knowledge on concentration inequalities.

**N.B.:** By "Riemannian manifold" I'll actually mean a smooth Riemannian manifold which is complete with the geodesic distance

$$d_p(x,y) := \inf_{\omega \in \mathcal C^1([0, 1], M) | \omega(0)=x,\omega(1) = y}\sqrt{\int_0^1\|\dot\omega(t)\|^2dt}.
$$

> **Definition (LSI)**. A probability distribution $\mu$ is said to satisfy a Logarithmic Sobolev Inequality with constant $\rho > 0$, written $\operatorname{LSI}(\rho)$, if for every probability distribution $\nu$ absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu$, it holds that
> $$
> H(\mu\|\nu) \le \frac{1}{2\rho}F(\mu\|\nu),
> $$
> where $H(\mu\|\nu)$ is [*relative entropy*](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/014.OV-Talagrand.pdf) and $F(\mu\|\nu)$ is [*relative Fisher information*](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/014.OV-Talagrand.pdf).

> **Definition (LC).** A probability distribution $\mu$ on a Riemannian nanifold $M$ is called log-concave with constant $\rho$, written $\operatorname{LC}(\rho)$, if there exists a
> a twice continuous differentiable potential field $V$ on $M$ such that $\mu = e^{-V(x)}dx$ and
> $$
> \operatorname{Hess}(V) + \operatorname{Ricc}(M) \succeq \rho I_d
> $$
> **Definition (GIPIC).** A probability distribution $\mu$ is said to satisfy GIPIC (Gaussian IsoPerimetic Inequality Corollary) with constant $\rho > 0$, if for every Borel set $B \subseteq M$ it holds that
> $$
> \mu(B_\epsilon) \ge 1 - \exp\left(-\frac{\rho}{2}(\epsilon-\sqrt{(2/\rho)\log(1/\mu(B))})^2\right),\;\forall \epsilon \ge \sqrt{(2/\rho)\log(1/\mu(B))},
> $$
> where $B_\epsilon$ is the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $B$.

And now, the real deal

> **Theorem [[Corollary 3.2 of Bobkov et al. 1999](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.397.5431&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [Corrolary 1.1 of Otto et Villani 2000]](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/014.OV-Talagrand.pdf).** On any Riemannian manifold, it holds that
> $$\operatorname{LC}(\rho) \implies \operatorname{LSI}(\rho) \implies \operatorname{GIPIC}(\rho).
> $$

## Application

If $M = \mathbb R^d$ and $\mu = d\gamma_{c,\Sigma} \propto e^{-V(x)}dx$ where $V(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x-c)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-c)$,
for some p.s.d matrix $\Sigma$ with largest singular value $\sigma^2$ and vector $c \in \mathbb R^d$, then $\operatorname{Hess}(V) + \operatorname{Ricc}(M) \succeq (1/\sigma^2 + 0)I_d = (1/\sigma^2)I_d$. Thus each multivariate Gaussian $d\gamma_{c,\Sigma}$ distribution on $\mathbb R^d$ satisfies GIPIC($1/\sigma^2$), more precisely, it holds that
$$
\gamma_{c,\Sigma}(B_\epsilon) \ge 1 - \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(\epsilon-\sigma\sqrt{2\log(1/\gamma_{c,\Sigma}(B))})^2\right),\;\forall \epsilon \ge \sigma\sqrt{2\log(1/\gamma_{c,\Sigma}(B))}.
$$

Comment: what is Ricc(.) ? moreover the largest singular value is same as the largest Eigen value and why does it come there ? –

Comment: $Ricc(M)$ is global Ricci curvature of the manifold $M$. In the case of Gaussian space, the the largest eigenvalue of $\Sigma$ appears because $Hess(V) \succeq (1/\sigma^2) I_d$ at all points $x \in M$.